# En cuales casos el IMEI de un dispositivo movil no esta disponible?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

Tengo una aplicación que necesita descargar datos, para eso se ha registrado previamente el `IMEI` del dispositivo en la base, ha funcionado bien el problema es que ahora que uso un dispositivo con la API 27 el `IMEI` me lo retorna null.

```
public  String getIMEINumber() {
    String IMEINumber = "";
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
    android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        TelephonyManager telephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            IMEINumber = telephonyMgr.getImei();                
        } else {
            IMEINumber = telephonyMgr.getDeviceId();           
        }
    }
    return IMEINumber;
}
```

He leído y veo que la documentación dice que retorna null si el `IMEI` no esta disponible, me pregunto en que casos no esta disponible? (si he agregado los permisos en el MANIFEST)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias situaciones por las cuales no podrías obtener el valor del IMEI, la primera es que es necesario el permiso

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

pero para versiones mayores a 6.0 debes requerir el permiso manualmente.

```
  if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);                    
            }
```

---

**Si estas usando un emulador este pude no obtener un valor IMEI.**

---

**Tratas de obtener un IMEI en un dispositivo que no es telefonico como una tablet, no obtendrías IMEI.**

---

Algunas veces `TelephonyManger.getDeviceId()` obtiene un valor null, por lo tanto si deseas un identificador para todos tus dispositivos, te puedo recomendar este método en el cual, si el valor obtenido es null  (usando `getImei()` o `getDeviceId()`) usar también `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID` que retorna un ID como una cadena hexadecimal única de 64 bits:

```
public String getUniqueID(){    
    String myAndroidDeviceId = "";
    TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            myAndroidDeviceId = mTelephony.getImei(); 
        } else {
            myAndroidDeviceId = mTelephony.getDeviceId(); 
        }          
    }else{
         myAndroidDeviceId = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID); 
    }
    return myAndroidDeviceId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La causa puede ser que el dispositivo no tiene IMEI, puesto que **sólo los dispositivos que soportan línea telefónica (para llamadas normales y SMS) tienen este identificador (IMEI).**
Por ejemplo algunas tablets no soportan línea telefónica (IMEI).

Si no tienes el dispositivo con tigo para verificar que soporte línea telefónica, puedes buscarlo en la web por el modelo y marca.

Si confirmas que este es el problema y tu aplicación necesita de manera obligatoria este Identificador(IMEI), tendrias que excluir estos dispositivos de los soportados por tu aplicación.